# How to write Fortran modules in UMAT subroutine in ABAQUS?

Tags: module, fortran, fortran90, subroutine, abaqus

I have 3 modules (in free form .f90 format) which are being called from inside of UMAT subroutine, such as:

```
module module_A  
use module_C  
use module_B  
....  
end module_A  

module module_B  
use module_C  
....  
end module_B

module module_C  
....  
end module_C

subroutine UMAT(STRESS,...)  

....  
Here the subroutines from module_A and module_B are being called  
...  
end subroutine UMAT
```

Now, my question is what should be the appropriate format of writing these modules with UMAT subroutine? How to merge different module files into a single *.for file (free format)?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you have multiple source files that you want to compile for your UMAT. Since the built-in Abaqus make utility only takes one file you can use an [`INCLUDE`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-include#FE57FE48-02EA-4A52-B0BD-C8120A0968FA) statement to tell the Fortran compiler to include other source files in the main source file. So let's say you have four files: module_A.for, module_B.for, module_C.for and umat.for. umat.for should contain some `INCLUDE` statements at the top:

```
INCLUDE 'module_C.for'
INCLUDE 'module_B.for'
INCLUDE 'module_A.for'

SUBROUTINE UMAT(... umat args ...)
    USE module_A

ENDSUBROUTINE UMAT
```

Make sure all of the *.for files are in the same directory so the compiler can easily find them. When the compiler encounters an `INCLUDE` it will read the referenced source file and continue compiling as if it's contents were directly in the umat.for source file, and then return to compiling umat.for.

Comment: Thank you Brady, for your reply. I will try to implement the your suggestions and let you know the results.Can I paste all the modules in the same source file one by one and at the end, paste the UMAT subroutine? Is it possible to do in this manner? If possible, what should be the appropriate format for doing that?

Comment: You can certainly include the source code of the various modules directly in the main source file. Simply paste their contents before the `SUBROUTINE UMAT` declaration, as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you @ brady for your reply. I am already on that job. However, your comment will give me more confidence.